# Spring Security OAuth 2 implicit grant - No support for refresh token

Tags: oauth, spring-security, access-token

Spring Security OAuth 2 implicit grant does not support refresh token. How is the scenario handled when access token expires at client side?

Answer (score 8):

The implicit flow does not grant the client a refresh token. This means that when the Access Token expires, the client has to redirect to the authorization link again.

When the access token expires, you will receive a 401 Unauthorized when requesting the protected resource (for example an API method):

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Some Realm Name", error="invalid_token",error_description="Invalid token: 12f55216-0fe0-422e-a473-356e03a3489b"
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml;charset=UTF-8

<oauth><error_description>Invalid token: 12f55216-0fe0-422e-a473-356e03a3489b</error_description><error>invalid_token</error></oauth>
```

Your application has to react and request a new access token by calling

```
/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=your-client-id
```

again.

[4.2. Implicit Grant](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31.html#rfc.section.4.2)

> "The implicit grant type is used to obtain access tokens (it does not
>   support the issuance of refresh tokens) and is optimized for public
>   clients known to operate a particular redirection URI. These clients
>   are typically implemented in a browser using a scripting language such
>   as JavaScript."

[4.2.2 Implicit Grant response](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31.html#rfc.section.4.2.2)

> "The authorization server MUST NOT issue a refresh token."

Comment: Is there a reason why refresh tokens are not supported in the implicit grant flow? Is this a security issue?

Comment: The refresh token would be exposed to a public client (browser) which could generate fresh access tokens without client authentication.
4.2. 3rd paragraph
`The implicit grant type does not include client authentication, and relies on the presence of the resource owner and the registration of the redirection URI. Because the access token is encoded into the redirection URI, it may be exposed to the resource owner and other applications residing on the same device.`

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this topic is quite old, but recently I've been facing same problem. 
In spring boot 2 and spring security 5, when springboot is Your authentication server, when You will call

/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=your-client-id
again, DefaultTokenServices.createAccessToken method will check if Your current token is still valid. When it is, You will receive Your old one, not refreshed as You would expect.
There is advise to use prompt=none parameter in request to receive refresh ed token, but as I noticed spring does not support it.

I solved this problem with overriding DefaultTokenServices with my CustomTokenServices. I described problem on my blog:

https://regulargeek.blogspot.com/2018/05/angular-5-springboot-2-oauth2-and.html

You will find sample app on my github:
https://github.com/aogorek/springboot-oauth2-angular2

I hope it will help some people because I didn't find better solution